# Traversing a little complex json array in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

how to iterate following a `JSON` in `JavaScript` returned from `PHP` AJAX response.

`[{
    "Topic": {
        "id": "1",
        "topic_name": "Playground"
    }
}, {
    "Topic": {
        "id": "2",
        "topic_name": "School Days"
    }
}, {
    "Topic": {
        "id": "3",
        "topic_name": "Sweet home"
    }
}]`

i am trying something like but not working

```
for (i in xmlhttp.responseText)
{   
  document.getElementById('wrap_main').innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText[i]['topic'].name + "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Does 'xmlhttp.responseText' return the right json string?

Comment: yes i printed the string in JavaScript and you can see the result in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parse to json if it's string:

```
var jsval = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
for(var i = 0; i < jsval.length; i++){
    document.getElementById('wrap_main').innerHTML+=jsval[i]['Topic'].topic_name + "<br />";
}
```